# What domains/IPs/ports are required to lock down access to SagePay?

Tags: opayo

I have an iPad that I want to access SagePay from, and nothing else. It is plugged into its own network, segmented by firewall. What domains/IPs/ports are required if I want to allow access to SagePay and nothing else?

Comment: "access to Sage Pay" - could you explain a little more what you are trying to do, and which Sage Pay gateway you would like to use? Are you intending to use 3D Secure?

Comment: What surprises me is there is no documentation from SagePage on this.

Answer (score 1):

Live IP range is: 195.170.169.0/25
Test IP:  195.170.169.8
Ports: 80 / 443